# Checar se um array possui valores vazios

Tags: php

Quero que este foreach cheque se existe valores vazios dentro do array, e caso exista, apresente a mensagem "erro".
Como posso fazer isso de maneira correta?

```
if (isset($_POST['start'])) {
foreach ($_POST['start'] as $key => $value) {
echo '<br>';
    $start2 = mysql_real_escape_string($value);  // data da saida
    $cod = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cod'][$key]); 
    $id_cotacao = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id_cotacao'][$key]);// id         
}}
```

Por Exemplo:

```
 linha 1 ==> 2017-12-01 | 10 | 21
 linha 2 ==> 2017-12-01 |    | 21
 linha 3 ==> 2017-12-01 | 10 | 21
```

Caso ele encontre uma variável vazia, mostra a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Pode utilizar a função [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não ficou muito claro pelo exemplo que você deu**, mas você pode fazer uma comparação contando o array recebido com o array 'filtrado' sem os índices vazios, basta usar [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) como no exemplo abaixo. Veja rodando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/uifDnB).

```
$post = [ 'a' => 'valor A' , 'b' => '' , 'c' => 'valor C' ];


if( count( $post ) !== count( array_filter( $post ) ) )
{
    echo 'erro!';
}
else
{
    echo 'ok!';
}
```

---

```
count( $post ) // output 3
count( array_filter( $post ) ) // output 2
```